# RSA decryption without Private Exponent

Tags: encryption, cryptography, openssl, rsa, private-key

I want to decrypt a 1024 bit data which was encrypted using RSA-public key encryption. 
I have access to

```
public key modulus, 
public key exponent, 
prime p, 
prime q, 
exponent1 (d mod(p-1)), 
exponent2 (d mod(q-1)) and 
coefficient ( (1/q) mod p )
```

I dont have access to private key exponent. Is there any way to decrypt the data without the RSA private exponent and all these available apis ?
I m using openssl for RSA operation. 
I heard that with chinese reminder therem, we need only p,q,exponent 1, exponent 2 and coefficient for RSA-decryption. But I'm looking for apis in openssl. Is there any useful way in openssl to decrypt without private exponent ?

Comment: Isn't the whole point of encryption (RSA and other; symmetric and asymmetric) that if you don't have the private part, you can't do anything of value?

Comment: @mah, i have rest of the things. With Chinese Reminder Theorem, I can get the result. But is there any way to use openssl for this type decryption ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is belongs on ITSecurity.com.

Comment: @mah, 'p' and 'q' are the basis for key.  With those values and the public exponent, you can generate the rest of the key values.

Answer (score 4):

Just check the openssl source for generating key pairs...

```
/* create r0, r1, r2, ctx and - of course - d */

/* calculate d */
if (!BN_sub(r1, p, BN_value_one())) goto err; /* p-1 */
if (!BN_sub(r2, q, BN_value_one())) goto err; /* q-1 */
if (!BN_mul(r0, r1, r2, ctx)) goto err;       /* (p-1)(q-1) */
if (!BN_mod_inverse(d, e, r0, ctx)) goto err; /* d */
return d;
```

You may need to generate some temporary variables in above...

Comment: That was problem with my input. I fixed it. It is working fine,

Comment: @jithin Don't forget to accept answers! I can see you have 11 questions still open. Not all have answers, but that's a few too many. Also note that many of your questions about crypto do not contain the cryptography or encryption tags. This means they only get picked up by persons following very specific tags. They will stay "under the radar" for most contributors.